# Is it possible to call an Excel add-in from VBA in Word in reasonably simple way?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word, excel-addins, cross-application

I have an add-in that helps fill Excel tables with data from Atlassian Jira, used by several kinds of Excel files. The add-in has been created with the Excel VBA editor, not VSTO.
Now I need to use the functions of this add-in from macros in a Word template.
To avoid duplicating the code base, I would like to use this add-in in Word.
Trying to add a reference to the Excel add-in in Word triggers the error "Can't add a reference to the specified file".
Is there a reasonably simple way to achieve this?

Comment: So you're trying to open an `xlam` in Word? Word can't open an Excel file.

Comment: You'd need to create an instance of Excel, load the add-in into that instance, then call the add-in functions.  Whether or not that's "relatively simple" is up for debate.

Comment: In short, there are ways to load it within an embedded Excel instance in the application, but depending on why you are doing it, you will most likely find that it proves to be completely pointless, as it's not going to be able to do what you expect it to do. Stop and think about WHY you are trying to do this, as that is much more important to consider than simply throwing an apple into a basket of oranges.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I think braX is right as I still won't be able to create a reference to the objects exposed by the add-in to use them from Word. So for now the only option left is to duplicate code into the Word realm...

Answer (score 0):

If you want the best next thing you can do is inserting Excel table into Word document and then adding to that document your VBA code.

To add the Excel tabel just use **Insert -> Table -> Excel Spreadsheet -> your toolbar will change to excel toolbar with the option for adding your VBA code like in Excel.**

[image]